# How to control FFT weighting coefficients in numpy or scipy?

Tags: numpy, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to re-implement a frequency identification algorithm described in Wolfram Mathematica manual here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html (unfold 'Applications')

The idea of this algorithm is that one performs two FFTs, first FFT roughly reveals the frequency, then the original signal is demodulated with the found frequency and a second FFT is performed. The second FFT finds a correction to the initially detected frequency, increasing the accuracy in the frequency beyond 1/T. Of course, this method has its limitations but works for me.

The trick is to weigh the second fft correctly. In Mathematica:

```
Fourier[pdata Exp[2 Pi I (pos - 2) N[Range[0, n - 1]]/n], FourierParameters -> {0, 2/n}]
```

Note the `FourierParameters -> {0, B}`, which changes the normalization coefficient in the FFT as: sum_i a_i e^(2 pi B (i-1)/n), and does the trick.

I cannot find anything similar in scipy or numpy implementations of fft. Is it possible to adjust the normalization coefficients in these implementations?